# Customize autocomplete dropdown in Coffeescript

Tags: javascript, jquery, coffeescript

I'm using Coffeescript . My source in autocomplete method returns me a hash (associated array) and i want to show some elements in dropdown list . I explain you more below

Firstly , I had this method calling in my coffeescript

```
jQuery ->
    $("#searchbox").autocomplete
        source: "/searches"
```

And response was 
 `["St James's Hotel","Criterion Restaurant"]` 
 so dropdown shows these labels correctly . but now I have response like

```
[
{"id":"ChIJD_XW2NcEdkgRS6oeZ95kXGo","label":"St James's Hotel"},
{"id":"ChIJYRe8_tMEdkgRr_J6bdITC1U","label":"Criterion Restaurant"}
]
```

so no dropdown is made while above response is visible in console . and i want only labels to be shown in dropdown. I have coffeescript like below now :

```
jQuery ->
    $("#searchbox").autocomplete
        source: "/searches"
        create: (event,ui) ->
         ui.item.label
        select: (event,ui) ->
            console.dir ui
            console.dir ui.item.id
```

Any help/guidline will be appreciating

**Update**
According to the official doc, if your objects have "label" and "value" properties, jQuery would know how to use it. I 've also tried that thing too ( means without involving create option ) . thanks by the way , I'm updating my question according to that

Answer (score 0):

According to the [official doc](http://api.jqueryui.com/autocomplete/), if your objects have "label" and "value" properties, jQuery would know how to use it. So can you change *id* by *value* in the source format? If not, you'll have to provide a function to the autocomplete and build an array of labels to show.

I don't know much of jQuery but it should be like this:

```
function getLabels(request, response) {
    // do ajax request to get the hash
    ajax.get('/searches?term=' + request, function(data) {
        data = JSON.parse(data);

        return data.map(function(obj) {
            return obj['label'];
        })
    });
}
```

Comment: Yeah dear , i know that and that's why i'm asking question I 've also tried that thing too ( means without involving create option ) . thanks by the way , I'm updating my question according to that

Comment: Ok, updated my answer to give an example of provider function.

Comment: dear i'm using coffeescript not jquery